# Disable optimistic locking globally in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

What's the best practice for disabling optimistic locking in Grails globally (for all the domain classes) if i'm not using Mongo?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to disabling optimistic locking in Grails globally then you can put in Config.groovy

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    version false
}
```

Comment: This works for all, not just Mongo. It is a technique I use quite often when dealing with legacy databases.

Answer (score 2):

By default GORM is configured with optimistic locking enabled. You can disable this by calling the version method with an argument of false:

In your domain class, set a mapping like this:

```
static mapping = {
// Used to disable optimistic locking
version false
}
```

[Here is a link for Reference](http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/#locking)

Comment: I was using `version: false` with two dots instead of without two dots.